# Custom Post Type template stored in plugin folder not showing in post attributes dropdown

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

I've created a plugin from which I want to load the template for my custom post type.
I've used this guide to load the template from plugin [Click Here!](https://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-page-templates-plugin/)

The templates are loaded perfectly in the `page` post type even though I've already specified the custom post type name in the page template header.

`Template Post Type: custom-post-type`

I can create a template in the theme folder and it perfectly works with custom post type.

Answer (score 1):

The templates in your plugin don't show up in your CPT because the templates are loaded from your **theme** (or child theme).

You'll need to either

1. Place the template in the root theme / child theme folder **or**
2. Create a placeholder template file that "calls" the original

In the second case (which I've had to do a few times), I use something like this for the template in the theme / child theme:

```
<?php
/** 
 Template Name: My Custom Template
 */

include WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/my-plugin/templates/my-template.php';
```

...while I'm sure there's a better way at it; this works quite well. If you want to get *really* fancy, you could also add something to the plugin's activation hook that copies this into the current theme.

Comment: But template from plugin works perfectly in default page type!